# What effect does the composableType node have on products

Tags: magento2

I am investigating adding new product types and a common argument in the product_types.xml is the composableType.

E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="simple" label="Simple Product" modelInstance="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Simple" indexPriority="10" sortOrder="10">
        <customAttributes>
            <attribute name="refundable" value="true"/>
        </customAttributes>
    </type>
    <type name="virtual" label="Virtual Product" modelInstance="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Virtual" indexPriority="20" sortOrder="40">
        <customAttributes>
            <attribute name="is_real_product" value="false"/>
            <attribute name="refundable" value="false"/>
        </customAttributes>
    </type>
    <composableTypes>
        <type name="simple" />
        <type name="virtual" />
    </composableTypes>
</config>
```

Does this refer to the products ability to be added to another product type like a configurable or a group? In the product type declarations for grouped and configurable there is no composableTypes node but the types **are** marked as composite="true" so that theory would make sense if it means what i think it means.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Defined product type under composableTypes that is used in to create config product grouped product and bundle products.

If you defined your custom product type under composableTypes, then you can utilize that product type as child product in config, grouped and bundle products.